# Rendering all form values after service call using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have an Angular article form that I'm populating using a service call. The problem is that, in order to get validation and data binding to work, I have to use `$setViewValue` and `$render` on each form input. What I'd like to do is simply set the data model for the form and then render the entire form somehow.

Here is a sample of what I have that works:

```
var _promise = articleService.getArticle($scope.params.articleId);
_promise.then(
    function(data) {
        $scope.articleForm.title.$setViewValue(data.item.title);
        $scope.articleForm.title.$render();
        $scope.articleForm.bodytext.$setViewValue(data.item.body);
        $scope.articleForm.bodytext.$render();
        $scope.articleForm.keywords.$setViewValue(data.item.keywords);
        $scope.articleForm.keywords.$render();
    },
    function() {
        $scope.setMessage('There was a network error. Try again later.', 'error');
    }
);
```

The code below accomplishes the same result visually (just doesn't render bindings, like updating fields to dirty in validation):

```
var _promise = articleService.getArticle($scope.params.articleId);
_promise.then(
    function(data) {
        // $scope.article breakdown: article.title, article.body, article.keywords
        $scope.article = angular.copy(data.item);
        // some sort of complete form render???
    },
    function() {
        $scope.setMessage('There was a network error. Try again later.', 'error');
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<form name="articleForm" novalidate role="form">
    <!-- TITLE -->
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : (articleForm.title.$invalid && !articleForm.title.$pristine) || (submitted && articleForm.title.$pristine) }">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="article.title" ng-minlength="3" required>
        <p ng-show="(articleForm.title.$error.required && !articleForm.title.$pristine) || (submitted && articleForm.title.$pristine)" class="help-block">A title is required.</p>
        <p ng-show="articleForm.title.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Title is too short.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- BODY -->
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : articleForm.bodytext.$invalid && !articleForm.bodytext.$pristine }">
        <label>Article Body</label>
        <div text-angular ng-model="article.body" ng-change="updateBody()" id="bodytext" name="bodytext"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- KEYWORDS -->
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : (articleForm.keywords.$invalid && !articleForm.keywords.$pristine) || (submitted && articleForm.keywords.$pristine) }">
        <label>Keywords</label>
        <input type="text" name="keywords" ng-model="article.keywords" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="150" required>
        <p ng-show="(articleForm.keywords.$error.required && !articleForm.keywords.$pristine) || (submitted && articleForm.keywords.$pristine)" class="help-block">At least one keyword is required.</p>
        <p ng-show="articleForm.keywords.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Keywords is too short.</p>
        <p ng-show="articleForm.keywords.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Keywords is too long.</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

I feel like there should a simple solution to this, since it's a common scenario, but I've searched high and low without a clear answer. Maybe I'm just approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: mm maybe I'm not getting the problem,what do you mean with 'data binding to work' and what kind of validations ?

Comment: as an example, when I set $scope.article.title = 'some title' in the controller, it doesn't trigger angular validation to change the classes (will still be pristine) or fire ng-change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution that works, but I don't think it's a better solution than just setting all the form fields individually. I'll post it here though, in case it helps anyone else in some way.

```
// set all the values via the angular model
$scope.article = angular.copy(data.item);

// without a timeout all the fields will still be unset (being asynchronous)
$timeout(function() {
    // loop through all the form values
    angular.forEach($scope.articleForm, function(value, key){
        if(typeof value === 'object' && key !== '$error'){
            // reset the view value and render, to process the updates on the form
            $scope.articleForm[key].$setViewValue($scope.articleForm[key].$viewValue);
            $scope.articleForm[key].$render();
        }
    });
});
```